# C++, random number w/ range of 1-6

Tags: c++, random

I was wondering what the way is to get a random number with a range of 1-6, using the rand() method. This is to simulate a dice roll needed for me to find the average of 3 dice rolls so the type will be double.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a random number in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445688/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c)

Comment: I think this question should be closed, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13445752/5550963

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a simple example to generate randoms between 1 to 6, I think you can figure the rest

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    std::cout << (rand() % 6 + 1) <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The terribleness of `rand()` aside, this is almost certainly going to be biased.