# Why not just use random_device?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I am a bit confused about the [C++11 random library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random).

What I understand: we need two separate concepts:

- random engine, which can be:

  - pseudo (needs seed) aka [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) (e.g. [`std::std::mt19937`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine))
  - true random number generator ([`std::random_device`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device))
- distribution: it maps the numbers obtained from the engine to a specific interval, using a specific distribution.

**What I don't understand** is why not just use the true random number generator:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 5);

// get random numbers with:
dist(rd);
```

As far as I can tell this works well.

Instead, what I found on most examples/sites/articles is that a PRNG is used (with the true random number generator being used just to seed the PRNG):

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 e{rd()}; // or std::default_random_engine e{rd()};
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist{1, 5};

// get random numbers with:
dist(e);
```

I am not talking about special use, e.g. cryptography, just your basic getting started articles.

My suspicion is because `std::mt19937` (or `std::default_random_engine`) accepts a seed, it can be easier to debug by providing the same seed during a debug session.

Also, why not just:

```
std::mt19937 e{std::random_device{}()};
```

Comment: _"the performance of many  implementations of random_device degrades sharply once the entropy pool is exhausted. For practical use random_device  is generally only used to seed a PRNG such as mt19937"_ [source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device)

Comment: @Michael That should be an answer

Comment: Well, an answer might want to go into more detail (e.g. _why_ the performance degrades). Hence why I posted it as a comment.

Comment: Regarding your last question; that is *exactly* how I frequently spin up a prng for many non-cryptographic-mandated purposes.

Comment: @Michael it might, but surely doesn't have to.

Comment: You call `std::random_device` a "true random number generator" but I would like to point out that this is not necessarily the case. The last time I used MinGW the implementation of `std::random_device` was not only pseudo-random, but it generated the same exact sequence every time you executed the program. This was really a poor choice on their part, but the standard did not forbid this. In my opinion this makes `std::random_device` next to useless.

Comment: @Chris_F yes, the standard allows this. However no major implementation uses a pseudo random engine for `std::random_device`. I have no data to back this up, but afaik MinGW is not used for any serious real world work/projects. It's mostly used by some students for school/homework. On linux gcc with libc++, clang with stdc++ and icc dominate the market. On Apple it's clang with stdc++. On windows is MSVC (with clang emerging in recent years) or gcc/clang via WSL (which is linux). And on embedded systems if they don't have a random hardware device, there's not much any implementation could do.

Comment: I don't have an official reasoning for this, but it's a pretty easy educated guess to say that the standard couldn't impose `std::random_device` to be a true random generator because C++ is supposed to work on all kinds of hardware, including embedded that don't have a mechanism to generate true random sequences. The standard committee hands are tied as long as C++ is supposed to be universal in this manner.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> Also, why not just:
>
> `std::mt19937 e{std::random_device{}()};`

It might be fine if you only will do this once, but if you will do it many times, it's better to keep track of your `std::random_device` and not create / destroy it unnecessarily.

It may be helpful to look at the libc++ source code for implementation of `std::random_device`, which is quite simple. It's just a thin wrapper over `std::fopen("/dev/urandom")`. So each time you create a `std::random_device` you are getting another filesystem handle, and pay all associated costs. (And whenever you read from it, you are making a system call.)

On windows, as I understand, `std::random_device` represents some call to a microsoft crypto API, so you are going to be initializing and destroying some crypto library interface everytime you do this.

It depends on your application, but for general purposes I wouldn't think of this overhead as always negligible. Sometimes it is, and then this is great.

I guess this ties back into your first question:

> Instead, this is what I found on most examples/sites/articles:

```
 std::random_device rd;
 std::mt19937 e{rd()}; // or std::default_random_engine e{rd()};
 std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist{1, 5};
```

At least the way I think about it is:

- `std::mt19937` is a very simple and reliable random generator. It is self-contained and will live entirely in your process, not calling out to the OS or anything else. The implementation is *mandated* by the standard, and at least in boost, it used the same code everywhere, derived from the original `mt19937` paper. This code is very stable and it's cross-platform. You can be pretty confident that initializing it, querying from it, etc. is going to compile to similar code on any platform that you compile it on, and that you will get similar performance.
- `std::random_device` by contrast is pretty opaque. You don't really know exactly what it is, what it's going to do, or how efficient it will be. You don't even know if it can actually be acquired -- it might throw an exception when you attempt to create it. It might make a system call whenever you read from it, so it may have much worse performance in terms of cycles-per-byte than `std::mt19937`. You know that it doesn't require a seed. You're not usually supposed to pull tons and tons of data from it, just use it to generate seeds. Sometimes, it acts as a nice interface to cryptographic APIs, but it's not actually required to do that and sadly sometimes it doesn't. It might correspond to `/dev/random` on unix, it might correspond to `/dev/urandom/`. It might correspond to some MSVC crypto API (visual studio), or it might just be a fixed constant (mingw). If you cross-compile for some phone, who knows what it will do. (And even when you do get `/dev/random`, you still have the problem that performance may not be *consistent* -- it may appear to work great, until the entropy pool runs out, and then it runs slow as a dog.)

The way I think about it is, `std::random_device` is supposed to be like an improved version of seeding with `time(NULL)` -- that's a low bar, because `time(NULL)` is a pretty crappy seed all things considered. I usually use it where I would have used `time(NULL)` to generate a seed, back in the day. I don't really consider it all that useful outside of that.

Comment: Rather than a `mt19937` PRNG that has a potential `2^19937 - 1` states (with its **624 32-bit elements**, i.e., a **`uint32_t state[624]`** vector), you have limited the `mt19937` to having, at most, `2^32` unique states with this single seed value - and therefore, at most, `2^32` random 'streams' of data. This *might* be ok for some applications, but the benefits of the `mt19937` PRNG are lost.

Comment: @BrettHale this is good general advice, but it isn't what the question asks. OP is asking why not just use `random_device` in the first place. Also I don't think it's reasonable to say that all the benefits of the mt19937 PRNG are lost. Even mt19937 seeded with a few bytes is better than libc rand function for a lot of purposes. There's a reason they built this "bootstrapping" mechanism into the standard library, so that you can seed mt19937 with a few bytes and it will stretch those few bytes to a full mt19937 state using another PRNG -- this is sometimes a useful technique

Comment: “”*** time(NULL) is a pretty crappy seed all things considered.***“”， could you please explain that in more details？

Comment: @John well for one thing, `time(NULL)` is seconds since the unix epoch, and has only second precision. If you spawn a bunch of threads and they generate seeds for RNG's in parallel, they may all get exactly the same seed, which in some programs could cause a problem. This cannot happen if they are getting seeds from `/dev/random`.

Comment: Even if they don't all get exactly the same seed, they still have seeds that may differ in only a few bits. That is going to put a lot of stress on the random number generator algorithm (to successfully make random numbers in different threads that are substantially different). Normally RNG's are designed with the assumption that seeds look completely random.

Answer (score 13):

[This article](http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/cpps-random_device.html) is a good point to start.

I'm going to synthesize just few points:

- It Has Unknown Cost.

  > How costly it is to read a number from this “device”? That is unspecified. It could, for example, be reading from /dev/random on a Linux system, which can block for an extended period waiting for entropy (which is itself problematic for a variety of reasons).

For my personal experience I've notified that `std::random_device` is usually slower than a simple Pseudo-randomic algorithm. That could be no true in general, but usually it does. That because it may involve physical devices, or other hardware than the simple CPU.

- It Might Actually Be Deterministic .

  > C++11's std::random_device is not required to be nondeterministic! Implementations can and do implement it as a simple RNG with a fixed seed, so it produces the same output for every run of the program.

Answer (score 11):

> Why not just use random_device?

This question is actually a very good one.

The answer is - of course you **can** just use [std::random_device](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) exactly like you written in your example. It is totally legitimate and correct use of `std::random_device` - and any distribution may be used on top of it just like with any other random engine. If you don't need [Pseudo-Random Number Generator (PRNG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) like [std::mt19937](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) or any other - just don't use it. That's it.

Mantra repeated by many people a la - "std::random_device is just for seeding blah-blah-blah" is a random BS (pun intended) that have nothing to do with the meaning and purpose of `std::random_device`. Sure though `std::random_device` **can** be used as a PRNG seed - just like any other source of random information.

Having said that - whether you actually **should** just use `std::random_device` instead of a good PRNG depends entirely on your application needs - some details written below.

You should view any PRNG as a mathematical function that takes limited size input sequence of bits and produces a very long output sequence of numbers with some (typically uniform) distribution. If you pass the same input bits to the same PRNG twice - you will get the same output sequence. Just like if you use the same value of `x` to compute `std::sin(x)` twice - you will get exactly the same sine value returned. That's why **if** you need to avoid repeating the same PRNG output number sequence each time - its input bits (seed) must be different each time. Obviously since PRNG operation requires nothing more than some computations - it is usually local and fast - no system calls, no external devices involved, no blocking while waiting for something, no exceptions thrown - instant result and high rate of numbers generated that scales easily when CPU performance increases.

`std::random_device` on the other hand is the first attempt to introduce actual random number generator in C++ standard library.

Quote from C++ standard (ISO/IEC 14882-2017):

> 29.6.6 Class random_device
>
> 1. A random_device uniform random bit generator produces nondeterministic random numbers.
> 2. If implementation limitations prevent generating nondeterministic random numbers, the implementation may employ a random number engine.

^^^ This quote is quite funny because (1) and (2) above entirely contradict each other. `std::random_device` either produces nondeterministic random numbers OR its implementation prevents it - both cannot possibly be true at the same time. But word "if" and "may" are present only in (2) - so the only possible non-contradictory understanding of the quote above is that **"if"** from (2) is never realized and every implementation just produces nondeterministic random numbers - i.e. complies with (1).

Let's just assume that standard compliant `std::random_device` simply produces uniformly distributed sequence of random and independent bits. If we are super optimistic we can even hope to get cryptographically secure random numbers - even though C++ standard doesn't guarantee or even promise anything like that. Good news is that modern implementations actually provide it - both typical `/dev/urandom` UNIX implementation and Win32 Crypto API implementation should be secure enough. Without being cryptographically secure `std::random_device` is not very useful tool anyway.

Especially since according to the C++ standard:

> **result_type operator()();**
>
> 6  *Returns:* A nondeterministic random value, uniformly distributed between **min()** and **max()**, inclusive.
> *It is **implementation-defined** how these values are generated.*

^^^ thus if we really need to - we may somewhat limit the portability of the application to only those implementations that produce cryptographically secure output of `std::random_device::operator()()` - as this is well defined and documented individually for each particular implementation (that's what **implementation-defined** means BTW). Of course if we don't need some strict requirements like secure random numbers we shouldn't limit the portability.

Obviously nondeterministic sequence of uniformly distributed and independent random bits (AKA true random numbers) cannot be produced without external source of information (external source of randomness) - like some sensor signal noise or precisely measured times of some external events - anything external and inherently irregular. (By external I mean that information comes from outside media - but the sensor itself may be integrated to CPU/SoC). Any such source of external randomness then typically filtered to remove detectable regularities to assure compliance with a requirement of uniformly distributed and independent bit sequence output. **All this greatly limits data rate produced and creates a possibility of failure and/or blocking while waiting for new external data.**

So let's now weigh pros and cons of PRNG sequence VS true random numbers for different kinds of applications.

1. If application requires random number generation for information security purposes - passwords, encryption keys, salt values, security tokens, etc. then there is no question - of all C++ standard features only `std::random_device` and not any compliant one (let alone non-compliant ones) but only those that provide cryptographically secure implementations. Some PRNGs may be used for information security purposes too but only special class of secure PRNG and only if they are carefully seeded with secure random seed of enough size (enough entropy) - so you need true random numbers anyway to produce a seed. As of now - no PRNG engine from C++ standard library is cryptographically secure. If you don't trust `std::random_device` to be secure (for example - you don't want to limit portability to suitable implementations only or you want to avoid the effort of checking implementation suitability for each supported platform after each update) then only non-standard trusted third party solution can be used safely - e.g. Win32 crypto API directly or UNIX /dev/random or /dev/urandom directly or some other non-standard solution - whatever is trustworthy enough for you.
2. Other sensitive applications where non-predictability of random numbers is very important - like online casinos, online betting, stock market trading, etc. - also probably require cryptographically secure random numbers - so all the considerations from (1) apply here too.
3. For most other applications - like usual games or scientific simulations or anything where money or security not involved and thus potential predictability of random number sequence cannot harm - typical good quality PRNG is sufficient. While it may be fine to still use `std::random_device` for many of these applications but only if performance (rate and delay of generation) is not important. In many cases performance is actually of major importance - e.g. for scientific simulations or real-time noise simulation (for computer graphics or sound effects, etc.) - so sometimes true random numbers are unsuitable for performance reasons.
4. Also there are applications where PRNG is fundamentally necessary - e.g. some games may generate maps/worlds/levels on the fly using PRNG with a fixed seed value to avoid storing them to save disk space (this was a popular trick on early computers with very little RAM and storage space but still used in some modern games too). Another example is noise substitution phase of audio/video compression algorithms - where actual background noise is replaced with PRNG-generated pseudo-noise of the same magnitude and spectral characteristics as the original noise to store just a seed to a compressed bitstream instead of lots of actual uncompressible random information.

**One last note:**

If you don't need secure random numbers and don't want to rely on quality or even standard compliance of `std::random_device` implementation then using it alone to generate PRNG seed is also a bad idea. You should put more randomness into the mix - e.g. combine `std::random_device` output with current time of maximum available precision (microsecond/nanosecond/whatever is available) and if available add some other external sensors' readings too (e.g. raw gyro sensor readings or audio mic readings or raw image sensor readings - anything external and noisy).

For example.
Instead of using this:

```
std::mt19937::result_type seed = std::random_device()();

std::mt19937 gen(seed);
```

Better use something like this:

```
std::mt19937::result_type seed = std::random_device()()
        ^ std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(
            std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
            ).count()
        ^ std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(
            std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
            ).count()
        /* ^ more_external_random_stuff */ ;

std::mt19937 gen(seed);
```

You may also initialize full state seed sequence of `std::mt19937::state_size` (=624) 32-bit numbers:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::array< std::uint32_t, std::mt19937::state_size >  seed_array;

for( auto it = seed_array.begin(); it != seed_array.end(); ++it )
{
    // read from std::random_device
    *it = rd();

    // mix with a C++ equivalent of time(NULL) - UNIX time in seconds
    *it ^= std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(
                    std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
                    ).count();

    // mix with a high precision time in microseconds
    *it ^= std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(
            std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
            ).count();

    //*it ^= more_external_random_stuff;
}

std::seed_seq sseq( seed_array.cbegin(), seed_array.cend() );
std::mt19937 gen(sseq);
```