# How std::random_device generate non-deterministic random numbers?

Tags: c++, random

Why std::random_device generate non-deterministic random numbers? What is the seed in this generator? It's not a time, so what?

Comment: Kind of explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39288595/why-not-just-use-random-device).  Trying to find a better dupe.

Comment: "If implementation limitations prevent generating nondeterministic random numbers, the implementation may employ a random number engine." [rand.device](http://eel.is/c++draft/rand.device#2)

Comment: [wikipedia useful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation)

Comment: `std::random_device` *should* generate non-deterministic values, but it doesn't have to. It depends on what the platform has to offer.

Comment: On bad implementations, `std::random_device` can sometimes just be implemented to return the same sequence of numbers every time. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880654/why-do-i-get-the-same-sequence-for-every-run-with-stdrandom-device-with-mingw).

Answer (score 1):

It is not specified. Implementation is supposed to provide suitable ways of doing this, and usually they would recourse to OS-provided tools.

For example, on Linux there are [/dev/[u]random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random) devices which will provide entropy from a system state.