# randomized array of numbers in wont pass integer range?

Tags: c++, arrays, random

```
long long x[1000000], n, small, big;
    main(){
        cin >> n; //range
        cin >> small; cin >> big;
        srand(time(NULL));
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
            x[i]=small + rand()%(big-small+1);
        }
        merge_sort(x,0,n-1);
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
            cout << x[i] << " ";
        }
    }
```

(ignore the merge_sort, i only used it to see the highest number)

So i make sure all the variables is in **long long**, yet all the randomized x[i] wont pass integer range (32768). Anyone have any idea why?

[some example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qalbF.jpg)

Comment: `main` is required to have the return type `int`.

Comment: The return type of `rand` is `int`. ( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand )

Comment: See [RAND_MAX](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/RAND_MAX). One of the many *many* reasons `rand` is terrible. Looks like your implementation supports the minimum required range.

Comment: Related, maybe a duplicate, maybe not (depends on if this is question is an XY problem): https://stackoverflow.com/q/13445688/1896169

Comment: note that instead of suggesting to ignore `merge_sort` you could simply remove the line from your code if it is not relevant for the question. See also [mcve]

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux -- all RNGs have a limited range. That doesn't make them terrible.

Comment: <shrug>. Many programmers fall into the fallacy that something that isn't perfect is useless. Especially in the area of random number generators, no generator is perfect, but only `rand` gets labelled useless. That's propaganda, not engineering.

Comment: I've removed my side of this conversation, as it's not productive and pollutes this comments section. Feel free to defend `rand` in any of the many questions that ask about why it's considered bad. Here's [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869166/why-is-the-use-of-rand-considered-bad) .

Answer (score 1):

Like all random-number generators, `std::rand()` produces numbers in a limited range. All the values are greater than or equal to 0, and all the values are less than or equal to `RAND_MAX`. The value of `RAND_MAX` depends on the implementation that you're using. You can look at it to see the upper limit:

```
std::cout << RAND_MAX << '\n';
```

There are techniques for creating larger or smaller ranges from the results of a random-number generator. With the newer `<random>` classes you'd use `std::uniform_int` to handle the details. With `std::rand()` you have to roll your own code.

To reduce the range, most people's first instinct is to use the remainder, as the code in the question does. That's okay, sort of, but it can introduce distortions. As an extreme example, suppose `RAND_MAX` is 32767, and you want to generate values in the range `[0 .. 32766]`. So you use `rand() % 32767`, which gives you values in that range. **But** there's a problem: whenever `rand()` produces a 0 you get a 0, when it produces a 1 you get a 1, etc., up to 32766. But when `rand()` produces 32767 you get 0. That is, you'll get 0 when `rand()` produces 0 **and** when it produces 32767, but you'll get other values for only one particular result from `rand()`. If `rand()` is perfectly uniform (no RNG is), you'll get 0 twice as often as you get any other value. When the range you want to generate is much smaller than the total range that the RNG produces this distortion isn't as large, and might be acceptable.

To do it right you have to discard values. The simplest way to discard values is just to ignore values larger than what you want:

```
int res = rand();
while (res > my_max_value)
    res = rand();
```

But if `my_max_value` is small, this will throw away a lot of values, wasting a lot of time. So a better approach is to combine discarding with taking the remainder:

```
int max = ((RAND_MAX + 1) / my_max_value) * my_max_value;
int res = rand();
while (res >= max)
    res = rand();
res %= my_max_value;
```

I haven't done that calculation exactly right; for example, if `RAND_MAX` is equal to `INT_MAX`, adding 1 will overflow. Fixing that is left as an exercise for the reader.

`max` will be the largest multiple of `my_max_value` that's less than or equal to `RAND_MAX`. The code discards values that are greater than or equal to that, and when it finds an appropriate value it takes the remainder.

To create a range that's larger than the range of the RNG you "tile" multiple values. For example, if `RAND_MAX` is 32767 and you need values in the range `[0 .. 1073741823]` (that upper limit is (32767 << 15) + 32767) you'd call `rand()` twice, shift one of the results left by 15, and add the other result. If you don't have such a convenient <g> value you have to create a range that's larger than your target range by tiling, then reduce the resulting range as I discussed earlier.

Note that all this stuff has to be done **regardless of the RNG that you're using**. It's much more convenient in C++11, when all those calculations are encapsulated in `std::uniform_int`, and that's a good reason for using the C++11 RNGs and distributions.