# Calling a random number generator in a method

Tags: c++11, random

I have used the code provided by Cornstalk in the link:
[How to generate a random number in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445688/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c)

It works fine if implemented within a function in my class, but I need to get random numbers in another function in that class, so the variable RNDRange (see below) must be defined at class-level. I then need to initialize it as below in function A, so I can call the variable in function B.

std::uniform_int_distribution RNDRange(0, MinimumNumberOfAnimals - 1);

With reference to the code below:

Made

std::mt19937 RandomNumberGenerator;

a class level variable and commented the same within function A. Works fine.

Tried to define RNDRange at class level so I can then initialize it in function A, and call RNDRange(RandomNumberGenerator) in function B. Since I am not able to define RNDRange at class level (don't know how) and then initialize it in function A, calling RNDRange(RandomNumberGenerator) in function B is not possible.

```
std::mt19937 RandomNumberGenerator; // Mersenne Twister pseudo-random generator of 32-bit numbers with a state size of 19937 bits
RandomNumberGenerator.seed(std::random_device()());
std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> RNDRange(0, MinimumNumberOfAnimals - 1); // Seeds a random number generator for the range between zero and MinimumNumberOfAnimals
double MyRnd;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // tests
{
    MyRnd = RNDRange(RandomNumberGenerator);
    MyRnd = MyRnd / MinimumNumberOfAnimals;
    // Use MyRnd 
}
```

Works fine within function A, but I can't understand how to define RNDRange at class level and then initialize with (0, MinimumNumberOfAnimals - 1) in function A. MinimumNumberOfAnimals is only defined in the constructor of the class.

Comment: Consider using [`std::uniform_real_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) instead of generating an `int` and divide it.

Comment: Thanks, but my issue is defining a class level variable for std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> RNDRange(0, MinimumNumberOfAnimals - 1);, not the double/int question, although that is also useful for improving the code.