# Random Number generator with range? C++

Tags: c++, random, numbers, generator

I am trying to make a C++ program for my Ebay business that is 15 digits long, but I want the first 5 digits to be the same.

Like ex: 152328476529876 PIN: 1000 152323123642345 PIN: 9433 152321254213432 PIN: 3222

I tried making a random number generator, but I cant get it to where the first 5 digits are the same, but the last 10 digits are the same. With a random pin.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
const int maximum_number = 9999999999;
const int minimum_number = 1;
unsigned int i;
const int maximum_pin = 999;
const int minimum_pin = 0;
unsigned int pin;
int main()
{

    // Print 100 random numbers
    for (int count = 0; count <= 1000; ++count)
    {
        const int new_number = (rand() % (maximum_number - minimum_number)) + maximum_number;
        const int new_pin = (rand() % (maximum_pin - minimum_pin)) + maximum_pin;
        std::cout << "15232" << new_number << " Pin : "<< new_pin << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
152321410094708 Pin : 1384

152321410073128 Pin : 1567 etc
```

The problem I am having is that the first 5 numbers are the same, which is how I want it, but then the 14100 remains the same and should be randomized as well, not just the last 5 digits...

Plus the pins only stay at 1000, they never go above 1999 etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a random number in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445688/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c)

Comment: The best way to generate uniformly distributed random number in modern C++ is describe in the following comment  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13445752/611560

Comment: Have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `rand()` and modulo operations, you should make use of the `<random>` header from C++11. Using Walter E. Brown's function toolkit from [n3847](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3847.pdf), you could use:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <random>

const uint64_t maximum_number = 9999999999;
const uint64_t minimum_number = 1;
const uint64_t maximum_pin = 9999;
const uint64_t minimum_pin = 0;
const uint64_t prefix = 15232;

auto& global_urbg() {
    static std::default_random_engine u{};
    return u;
}

void randomize() {
    static std::random_device rd{};
    global_urbg().seed(rd());
}

uint64_t pick_a_number(uint64_t from, uint64_t thru) {
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<uint64_t> d{};
    using parm_t = decltype(d)::param_type;
    return d(global_urbg(), parm_t{from, thru});
}

int main() {
    randomize();
    for (int count = 0; count < 100; ++count) {
        const uint64_t new_number = pick_a_number(minimum_number, maximum_number);
        const uint64_t new_pin = pick_a_number(minimum_pin, maximum_pin);
        std::cout << prefix << std::setw(10) << std::setfill('0') << new_number
                  << " Pin : " << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << new_pin << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
152325021252553 Pin : 1766
152327824160815 Pin : 7717
152321697896629 Pin : 3659
152320879192254 Pin : 8832
152325057425972 Pin : 2831
152323353939394 Pin : 1681
152324684928448 Pin : 9800
152328117866049 Pin : 4173
152326884989008 Pin : 4663
152320007759205 Pin : 7264
152327718061191 Pin : 3968
152322605655403 Pin : 8213
152324442390907 Pin : 7916
152322386351545 Pin : 4683
152321687805442 Pin : 3886
152328171047426 Pin : 6344
152327001747780 Pin : 2636
152325373164268 Pin : 3676
```

Comment: @michael You are welcome. Also check out the rest of n3847, which I justed added the link for.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that generating a random number with rand() gives you a number between 0 and at least 32767 (depending on your platform, see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm)) and this number is not large enough. Another problem is that the datatype `int` does not have enough bits to store such a large number.

This is all very platform dependant but these are the minimal sizes:

- `int` uses at least 16 bits which can store numbers from 0 to 65536 (if unsigned)
- `long` uses at least 32 bits which can store numbers from 0 to 4294967296 (in unsigned)
- `long long` uses at least 64 bits which can store numbers from 0 to 18446744073709551616 (if unsigned)

So you already have a problem with your max values since they do not fit inside an int. If you want to be sure how large your numbers can be you can use [`stdint.h`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/) and specify your `ints` with `uint64`, `int32` and such.

What you want is 10 random digits. This can be achieved with something like this:

```
for (int count = 0; count < 1000; count++) {
    // leading number must not be 0
    long long randomNumber = (rand() % 9) + 1;

    for (int i = 0; i<9; i++) {
        randomNumber *= 10;
        randomNumber += rand() % 10;
    }
    std::cout << "15232" << new_number << "\n";
}
```

The Pin has a similar problem I think

Comment: That works better than mine! Thank you! the only issue I have is that some of the digits are only 8 long and not 10.

Comment: Oh i forgot, if the leading number is 0 the number will be truncated -> 0034 -> 34. A simple solution would be to add a leading non zero number. But since 0 is not possible anymore there are a few less numbers. I added it above but if you want to have leading 0s you should use a string (char array).

Comment: It's advised not to use modulo as it introduces a bias in the resulting distribution random number distribution, see this for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator

Comment: Yes you are right! But since this is not security relevant and he need to check for duplicates anyway this should be just fine for this purpose.

Comment: @YannDroneaud -- while that's theoretically true, in practice the bias is insignificant for small ranges. If `RAND_MAX` is 32727 (that's the minimum allowed value; many RNGs have a much larger range), using `%9` or `%10`  will introduce a bias on the order of one part in 3000, i.e., ~.03%.

Comment: @PeteBecker you're right, but C++ provides the necessary tool to be safe regardless of the ranges, so they must be preferred.

Comment: @YannDroneaud — engineering is about evaluating tradeoffs, not blindly applying “rules”. More complicated and slower is not a clear win over minor bias.