# rand() function generates the next number by ascending to the previous number

Tags: c++

Please check code given below. The random number it generates for each execution is the increment of the previous generated number in the previous execution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    cout<<"\n Random Number : "<<rand()<<endl;

    cin.get();
    return 1;
}
```

Please executeit for 5-6 times and you will see that the random numbers are increasing for each execution and they are very close to each other.

Note : Please use CodeBlocks or Visual studio to check it, not the online compilers.

Comment: There are almost no guaranties on the randomness of `rand()`. Your behavior may be due to the fact that `srand` is seeded with slightly larger values (the current time) each time you test. It might just be returning the seed on the first call each time, or something closely related to it.

Comment: you say "the next generated random number is always bigger" but you only look at `rand()%500`, hence you dont really know if the next number is bigger or smaller. `rand()` is known to be of poor quality and naively taking `%` is one way to observe that

Comment: `time(NULL)` gives you the time in seconds as an integer, so if you call the program twice in the same second, you will get the same number twice. If you call it in the next second, you will get completely different numbers: https://ideone.com/McE7CD

Comment: moreover you seem to compare random numbers where each is generated with a different seed, where the seed have a strong relation. To get anything meaning full you would have to look at lots of random numbers generated from the same seed

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445688/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c ?

Comment: I think my question have nothing to do with ill-formed main definiton @eerorika

Comment: @mch As I already mentioned above, "When I put `x = rand()%500; part in a loop ... it works properly". But the problem arises from execution of the program I guess.

Comment: @bashburak did you see the `+ i` in `srand(time(NULL) + i);` in my example? It will simulate 100 program calls each with a  1 second gap.

Comment: @mch it also works if you do not put +i in srand(rime(NULL)). It still works properly when you do with loops. Because execution happens one time only. Check here : [link](https://ideone.com/Tkha11)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a random number in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445688/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c)

Answer (score -1):

Actually I found a way to solve my problem but still it might not be an answer to my question. 
Anyway the problem is not about `srand()` or `rand()` functions but it is about the function `time(NULL)`. Since I am trying to run this code on Windows, instead of using `time(NULL)` as a parameter for `srand()`, I used `GetTickCount()` and now it generates random numbers properly for each execution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(GetTickCount());

    cout<<"\n Random Number : "<<rand();

    cout<<"\n";
    cin.get();
    return 1;
}
```