# Rolling dice number not being recognized in if statement

Tags: c++

I got a small program where in the end, the program asks the user if he/she wants to roll dice to win an extra 15% off their initial check, but my if statement is not recognizing that if the user rolls a 6, they win the discount.  When the dice eventually rolls a 6, it still reads as a fail and tells the user to pay the full amount.  How can I work around this?

My class:

```
class roll
{
private:
    int high;
public:
    roll(int high = 6)
    {
        this->high = high;
    }

    ~roll()
    {

    }

    int rolled(int amt = 1)
    {
        int done = 0;

        for (size_t x = 0; x < amt; x++)
        {
            done += rand() % high + 1;
        }
        return done;
    }

};
```

My if statement:

```
  cout << "Would you like to play a dice game for a discount? Y/N: " << endl;
            cin >> res;
            if (res == 'Y' || res == 'y')
            {
                srand(time(static_cast<unsigned>(0)));
                roll one;
                cout << one.rolled() << endl;
                if (one.rolled() == 6)
                {
                    cout << "Congratulations!  You won 15% off your meal!!!" << endl;
                    prize = grandtot - (grandtot * .15);
                    cout << "Your final total will be $" << prize << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Sorry, you did not win, pay the original amount!" << endl;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Thank you, pay the original amount and have a nice day!" << endl;
            }
```

Comment: Remember that `rolled` will (usually) return a different number if you call it a second time. (I think everyone falls into this trap more or less regularly.)

Comment: Calling `one.rolled()` twice can produce different values.   So the `cout << one.rolled() << endl` may output a different value than is then tested in `if (one.rolled() == 6)`.   Store the result of `one.rolled()` in a variable, then print and test the value of that variable.

Comment: `prize = grandtot - (grandtot * .15);` is equivalent to `prize = grandtot * .85;`

Comment: `srand(time(static_cast<unsigned>(0)));` You should call this 1 time at the beginning of main and avoid putting it in a loop. Remember that the resolution of the clock is 1 second. And also if the seed is the same you get the same random sequence. Meaning if this loop executes fast enough you will get the same roll multiple times in a row.

Comment: class roll is completely unnecessary. It could have been a simple function.

Comment: Please don't use `rand()`. There's whole c++11 new library `<random>` that does RNG correctly.

Comment: @ThomasSablik - not necessarily.   Neither 0.15 not 0.85 can be exactly represented using floating point, so subtracting either from one does not (necessarily) give exactly the other.     Floating point is like that.

Comment: *`~roll() {}`* – Why do you write that?

Comment: *`roll(int high = 6) { this->high = high; }`* – Use the initialization list: `roll(int high = 6) : high{ high } {}`

Comment: @UmNyobe it would if it was refactored to have `roll()` and `getRolled()` then the fact that `rolled()` re-rolls the dice wouldn't be quite so misleading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, look at @PaulEvans answer for your question. I want to put some focus on your `rolled` function:

```
int rolled(int amt = 1)
{
    int done = 0;

    for (size_t x = 0; x < amt; x++)
    {
        done += rand() % high + 1; // <= This line
    }
    return done;
}
```

Pay attention that you are using `rand` function to get random values. It's true that you can get random values by using this function, but I would recommend to use C++11 way - with better distribution (don't forget #include ):

```
int rolled(int amt = 1)
{
    int done = 0;
    std::random_device dev;
    std::mt19937 rng(dev());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> dist6(1,6); // distribution in range [1, 6]

    for (size_t x = 0; x < amt; x++)
    {
        done += dist6(rng); // <= This line
    }
    return done;
}
```

For more details see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13445752/8038186

Answer (score 5):

You're not storing your roll, you want this instead:

```
const int current_roll = one.rolled();
cout << current_roll << endl;
if (current_roll == 6)
...
```