# How can I randomly iterate over each element of vector without repetition

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I tried using `rand()` with `srand()` to generate random index numbers but i still get indices repeating is there any other way of iterating over all elements of a vector buy getting the indices randomly without affecting order of vector elements
I cant `random_shuffle()` because random shuffle changes the order of my vector elements whose order is critical.

Comment: Stop using `rand()` and start [using `<random>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13445752/1870760).

Comment: Can you make a copy of the vector and shuffle that instead?

Comment: I have just tried using `random_device dev;
  mt19937 rng(dev());
  uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> dist6(0, ICSC.size()); // distribution in range [1, 6]
  cout << dist6(rng) << std::endl;` which still has repetition.

Comment: So shuffle a vector of indices, and then get your vector elements by index. There isn't a much better way of randomly sampling without replacement that I'm aware of, because you need to track which indices you already consumed.

Comment: `shuffle()` still destroys the order, because i need every 4 vector elements starting from beginning to stay together.

Comment: Thanks let me try creating an array of indices.

Answer (score 10):

Use [std::iota](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) to fill a vector with indices. Then use [std::shuffle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) to shuffle the index vector. Use the index vector to iterate your main vector.

Implementation left as practice to the OP.

Comment: I solved the problem by creating a vector with indices but i did not use `std::iota`

Comment: @TonyMogoa great. I prefer `std::iota` myself, it is handy :)