# error: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned long'

Tags: c++

I am using clang++ "file.cpp" -std=c++14 -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat to compile my program.
Now I get this following error code:

warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-conversion]

The error line is this:

`v_rand = rand() % (english.size());`

The whole code of error:

```
void trainer_es (string lang)
{

    ifstream in("dictionary_es.txt");
    if(!in)
    {
        cout<<"ERROR"<<endl;
        }

    string line;
    int right=0;
    int wrong=0;
    vector<string> english, spanish;
    bool is_english = true; 
    while(in.eof()==0)  
        { 
            getline(in,line);
            if(is_english   
            {
                english.push_back(line);
            }
                else 
            {
            spanish.push_back(line);

            }
        is_english = !is_english;   
        }

    in.close();

    unsigned long v_rand;
    srand(unsigned (time(nullptr)));

    if (lang == "english")
    {
        for (unsigned long int i=0; i<deutsch.size()-1; i++)
        {

            v_rand = rand() % (english.size());
            cout<<"Translate the word: "<<english.at(v_rand)<<endl;
            cin>>line;

            if(line == spanish.at(v_rand))
            {
                cout<<"right!"<<endl;
                right++;
            }

            else 
            {
                cout<<"wrong"<<endl;
                cout<<"the correct word is: "<<spanish.at(v_rand)<<endl;
                wrong++;
            }

        } 
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?

Answer (score 5):

[`rand()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) returns an `int`, which is signed. [`english.size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) returns a [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t), which is unsigned. So, to compute the expression `rand() % english.size()`, the return value of `rand()` will need to be cast to an `unsigned` type.

This causes an implicit conversion from `int` to `unsigned long`, which is throwing this warning.

I'd strongly suggest looking into [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution), which you can specify a return type for. [Here's a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13445752/2602718) of how to use it.