# Why ı cant print the string?

Tags: c++, printing

I am new at the c++. I made basic random string program but I cant print the string to console. These are my codes :

[image]

Comment: Do not post your code as image. Please post your code as text directly in your question. Also note that functions must be declared or defined before being used.

Comment: Please paste your code and apply markdown syntax instead of a code-screenshot next time :)

Comment: `#include <string>` is missing.

Comment: There are many issues in your code. For example it should be `string& line`. Even better, the string should be returned by the function. Moreover, the size of `line` is not defined. So you have out-of-bound access with `line[i]`

Comment: Your case is wrong:
1. You are using a copy inside your randomString function, not reference;
2. You are using [] operator but your string is empty. So it is UB.

Comment: `line[i] = character;` should be `line += character;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not include `<string>` and also you take the string by copy, to edit it you'll have to pass it by reference using `&`

```
#include <string>
void randomString(std::string& line)
```

you don't need to assign a number to int and then assign it to char, char is an integer value in c++ so you can:

```
char character = rand()%122 + 97;
```

with this method your random numbers will not be very good, you can look into [How to generate a random number in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445688/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c)

you access your string with [] operator and it has not yet been defined, to add a character to a string just use

```
line += character;
```

also if you want a random number length, there is no need for the boolean and i++ stuff:

```
int charNumb = rand() % 8 + 4;
while(charNumb--)
```

will do just fine and it looks much cleaner.