# How to use srand() in a class function and yield different results

Tags: c++, function, random

I am trying to create a class in c++ where the class functions calculate a chance of something happening. But when I try to implement the functions using `srand(time(0))` it just produces the same outcome every time. `mooseChance` is a private variable of the class `Hunting`. How do implement `srand(time(0))` to get random odds in the function call?

```
    void Hunting::calcMooseChance()
    {
        srand(time(0));
        bool mooseAppear = false;
        mooseAppear = (rand() % 100) < 50;
        mooseChance = mooseAppear;
    }
```

Comment: Just call `srand` once at the start of your program or even better use the c++11 random library which is much higher quality

Comment: A fairly dumb fix is to change `srand(time(0));` to `srand(time(0)^rand());`

Comment: [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7343833/995714). But you don't use srand in C++. Use [`std::random_device `](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13445688/995714) instead