# How do I select a random item out of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm making a rock paper scissors bot that randomly picks rock, paper or scissors. I have an array called `rpsoptions` as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
   std::string rpsoptions[3] = {"rock", "paper", "scissors"};
   std::cout << ( RANDOM ITEM FROM ARRAY) << std::endl;
}
```

How do I select a random element from the array?

Comment: don't know why this was closed but hey you can use rand and srand for this

Comment: Agree, the duplicate is wrong. Am voting to reopen.

Comment: @JoshKisb Please don't recommend `rand` and `srand`: [Why is the use of rand() considered bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869166/why-is-the-use-of-rand-considered-bad) You should use the [random library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Comment: oh.. any better alternative

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do this in a 'high-level' way and pull the random element out of the array in a single step. Your first step would be to generate a random integer in the range of the number of elements in your array, and then use that randomised index to access the corresponding element in your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this by:

1. Generating a random index into the array (in your case between 0 and 2); let that index be `i`.
2. Emitting `rpsoptions[i]`.

As @ThomasSablik notes, the first step is covered by this question:

[How to generate a random number in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445688/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c)

Combining the two steps, here is what you could get for your program:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::random_device dev;
    std::mt19937 randomness_generator(dev());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> index_distribution(0,2);

    std::string rpsoptions[3] = {"rock", "paper", "scissors"};

    auto i = index_distribution(randomness_generator);
    std::cout << rpsoptions[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Note that I've glossed over the issue of seeding the pseudo-random number generator; that's covered in the first answer at the link above, and would result in a bunch more code. It's important when you actually want to rely on properties of your random distribution, but not so important to illustrate the way you use the (pseudo-)randomly-generated index.

Answer (score -1):

You only need to generate a random number and use it to choose the element into the array:

```
    int main() {
        srand(time(NULL));
        std::string rpsoptions[3] = {"rock", "paper", "scissors"};
        std::cout << rpsoptions[rand() % 3] << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

where `rand() % 3` generates a random integer number in [0, 2] range (number of the elements in the array you have).

Comment: It is generally [not a good idea to use `rand()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869166/why-is-the-use-of-rand-considered-bad). Its problems do not manifest in your specific example, but if op decides to take up its use, she will likely encounter its deficiencies.