# How do I display a random element of a vector?

Tags: c++, random

I am trying to display "first", "among", "shift", "debug", and "craft" randomly, but it prints "shift" every time I run the project. In case this has anything to do with my problem, I'm using Xcode on macOS Ventura.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector <string> vec {"first", "among", "shift", "debug", "craft"};
    int rand_num = rand() % vec.size();
    string word;
    word = vec[rand_num];
    
    cout << word;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I expected it to display "first", "among", "shift", "debug", or "craft" randomly, but it only printed "shift"

Comment: Did you try seeding the random number generator?

Comment: Every C or C++ textbook that explains `rand` also explains another function too, and provides detailed instructions for how to use it correctly. What does your textbook say?

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) if you're actually trying to learn c++.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a random number in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445688/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

The `rand()` function gives a random value between `0` and `RAND_MAX` which will be same every time you run the program unless you seed it using the `srand()` function. Your code does not use `srand()` so `rand_num` is initialized with the same value every time you run the program.

Comment: *I am new to the platform* - "Member for 2 years, 4 months". Hm... Anyway, welcome! ;)

Comment: Lol, i made the account way back but hardly ever used it.

Answer (score 2):

`rand()` generates a pseudo-random sequence of numbers that will be the same given the same seed. Since you aren't explicitly initializing the seed using `srand`, you keep getting the same random value.

One way of initializing it so it gets a different seed in each execution is to use the current time:

```c
// Must be called before you call rand:
srand (time(NULL));
```