# I am trying to generate random numbers on c++ but to no avail. What's the problem?

Tags: c++, random

I am trying to allocate digits 1 to 9 to a,b,c..i. I am trying to find each random number using a counter method. So each time a variable isn't equal to another variable, it gets a point. Once it gets 8 points, that number gets assigned to the variable.

I have done the same for all variables. I have attached my code below. There are 3 code blocks.

1. Main file
2. the functions file
3. the header file

You may find some extra constraints in the conditions in the functions file, but they are for another problem which I don't think is relevant.

main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include "test.hpp"
using namespace std;


int main() {
 srand((unsigned)time(0));
 int A = 0, B = 0, C = 0, D = 0, E = 0, F = 0, G = 0, H = 0, I = 0, sum = 0;
 
 no (A);
 while (C == A or C == 0) {
    no (C);}
 while (B == A or B == 0 or B == C) {
    no (B);}
 while (D == A or D == 0 or D == C or D == B) {
    no (D);}
 while (E == A or E == 0 or E == C or E == B or E == D) {
    no (E);}
 while (F == A or F == 0 or F == C or F == B or F == D or F == E) {
    no (F);}
 while (I == A or I == 0 or I == C or I == B or I == D or I == E or I == F) {
    no (I);}
 while (G == A or G == 0 or G == C or G == B or G == D or G == E or G == F or G == I) {
    no (G);}
 while (H == A or H == 0 or H == C or H == B or H == D or H == E or H == F or H == I or H == G) {
    no (H);}
 
 
 
 cout << A << " is A \n";
 cout << B << " is B \n";
 cout << C << " is C \n";
 cout << D << " is D \n";
 cout << E << " is E \n";
 cout << F << " is F \n";
 cout << G << " is G \n";
 cout << H << " is H \n";
 cout << I << " is I \n";

   
}
```

functions file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include "test.hpp"




void no(int & x) {

x = (rand() % 9) + 1;

}
```

hpp file (test.hpp)

```
void no(int & x);
```

At first, I was getting some absurd numbers like 0, -1934, or 42130. So, I tried to use a different method to generate random numbers. At first, I was using the `<cstdlib>` library, but then I switched to the `<random>` library as you can see. I think that's when I stopped getting any output at all.

After that, I tried to stop using the `std` namespace, but that didn't really help, either.

Then I re-read my code a bunch of times and tried to rewrite it, but still of no use.

So, I am thinking maybe a flaw in my logic? If so, what?

Comment: Move `srand((unsigned)time(0));` to the first line of `int main()` and never call it anywhere else in your code. Calling it multiple times is a bug because if that happens on the same second you get the same random numbers because of the same seed.

Comment: C++ has [amazing random number facilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that mean you don't have to use the feeble and unpredictable `rand()`.

Comment: PSA: Avoid using global variables if you can. There's really no reason here to use such things. This could all be trivially encapsulated inside a super simple C++ class.

Comment: The issue can be demonstrated with a lot less code. See about [mre].

Comment: `srand()` and `rand()` are really part of C and have a lot of well documented flaws. C++ has a much better random number generation library. [How to generate a random number in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13445752/14065)

Comment: Also a word of advice is to avoid repeating yourself. Your functions look pretty much the same except for a single line. You could refactor this to be a single function that returns the 1 value and also remove the global variables.

Comment: Do you just want a random shuffle? [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)

Comment: Don't let the naysayers get to you; `srand` and `rand` work just fine for what you're doing, and you don't need to learn the more complex new stuff now, although you'll probably want to switch in the future. And, as one comment has indicated, call `srand()` exactly once at the beginning of the program. (You'd have the same issue with the new stuff, too)

Comment: `void no_a(int & x);` x is passed by reference so `no_a (A);` would change both `A` and `a`.

Comment: @drescherjm moved srand((unsigned)time(0)); to the first line of int main(), removed the global variables, only have a single function but code still doesn't give anything out. So, I am going to try some of the new methods you and the others have suggested.

Comment: @PeteBecker, I have tried calling srand() only once but that didn't help. what do you suggest since the new methods are going to have the same issue

Comment: If you have no output at all maybe this is the issue: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately)

Comment: If you have some other problem you will probably have to install a debugger and use it. Set a breakpoint in `int main()` after `std::cout << B << " is B \n";` and see if anything is printed at all.

Comment: I did not expect these while loops. My new guess is one of the while loops is an infinite loop. If you had a debugger you could see that quickly by pressing the pause button and inspecting the variables. Then play and pause again and see if it advances.

Comment: I have replaced my code to be more readable and added more modifications. @drescherjm other programs run. It's just this one. Is it because there is a probability that at least one of the numbers is equal to each other so the code keeps running forever?

Comment: I see, which debugger do you recommed? @drescherjm

Comment: `while (C != A or C != 0) {` would always loop unless both C and A are both equal to 0.

Comment: ***I see, which debugger do you recommed?*** It depends on your OS. On MS Windows using Visual Studio Community as your IDE will likely be your best experience. It comes standard with the compiler and a very good debugger.

Comment: @drescherjm yea fixed it. It works now. I have updated the code. I just seem  to have gotten confused with all the repetitions in the code that it was hard for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You only need two files, one header, and the main file, using the "functions file" is an incorrect way of doing it, also in C++, we don't use `or`, but instead use `||`, here's a debugged version of your files:

***`test.hpp`***

```
#include <random>

void random_digit(int & x) {

    x = (rand() % 9) + 1;

}
```

***`main.cpp`***

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.hpp"
using namespace std;


int main() {
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    int A = 0, B = 0, C = 0, D = 0, E = 0, F = 0, G = 0, H = 0, I = 0;
    
    random_digit(A);
    while (C == A || C == 0) {
        random_digit(C);}
    while (B == A || B == 0 || B == C) {
        random_digit(B);}
    while (D == A || D == 0 || D == C || D == B) {
        random_digit(D);}
    while (E == A || E == 0 || E == C || E == B || E == D) {
        random_digit(E);}
    while (F == A || F == 0 || F == C || F == B || F == D || F == E) {
        random_digit(F);}
    while (I == A || I == 0 || I == C || I == B || I == D || I == E || I == F) {
        random_digit(I);}
    while (G == A || G == 0 || G == C || G == B || G == D || G == E || G == F || G == I) {
        random_digit(G);}
    while (H == A || H == 0 || H == C || H == B || H == D || H == E || H == F || H == I || H == G) {
        random_digit(H);}



    cout << A << " is A \n";
    cout << B << " is B \n";
    cout << C << " is C \n";
    cout << D << " is D \n";
    cout << E << " is E \n";
    cout << F << " is F \n";
    cout << G << " is G \n";
    cout << H << " is H \n";
    cout << I << " is I \n";

    return 0;
}
```

***OUTPUT***

```
4 is A 
1 is B 
9 is C 
5 is D 
2 is E 
7 is F 
6 is G 
3 is H 
8 is I
```

But there's a problem with this approach, since you are using a comparizon with a random in a while loop, wich is a very bad practice. This code's performance will vary A LOT, and theretically, may never finish, fortunately there's a better way of getting random unique numbers in a range using arrays instead of multiple variables by just shuffling the an array of numbers, and even better, you can choose what numbers are gonna be shuffled by modifying the elements of the `numbers` array:

***`test.hpp`***

```
#include <random>

int random_int(const int &min, const int &max) { //random number between min and max (inclusive)

    return (rand() % (max - min + 1)) + min;

}
```

***`main.cpp`***

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.hpp"
using namespace std;


int main() {
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    int numbers[9] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int numbers_size = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(int); //get the amount of elements in numbers

    //shuffle the numbers array
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers_size - 1; i++) {
        const int swap_index = random_int(i, numbers_size);
        const int temp = numbers[i];
        numbers[i] = numbers[swap_index];
        numbers[swap_index] = temp;
    }

    //output the elements of numbers array
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers_size; i++) { 
        cout << numbers[i] << " is " << char('A' + i) << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative  `and` and `or` aren't the only things that have alternate names.